# Multiline UILabel?

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel

I need insert to `UILabel` multiline text. I do the following:

```
NSMutableString * spName = [[NSMutableString alloc ]initWithString:@""];

for (NSUInteger i=0; i<arrEx.count; ++i)
{
    ExInfo * exInf = [arrEx objectAtIndex:i];
    [spName appendString:[MyObject getName:exInf.spNum]];
    [spName appendString:@" "];
    [spName appendString:exInf.totalTime];
    [spName appendString:@"\n"];        
}

CGSize size = [spName sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] 
                 constrainedToSize:constraint
                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

[cell.exsInfoLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, top, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), size.height)];
[cell.exsInfoLabel setText:spName];
[spName release];
```

`arrEx` consists of two items, so it should be two strings. But the `UITableViewCell` contains only the first string.
In IB I set count of lines to 0 for the UILabel `cell.exsInfoLabel`.

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
CGSize labelsize;
UILabel *commentsTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[commentsTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[commentsTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
NSString *text = @"yourtextString";
[commentsTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"size:14]];
labelsize = [text sizeWithFont:commentsTextLabel.font 
             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(268, 2000.0) 
                 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
commentsTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 24, 268, labelsize.height);
[cell.contentView addSubview:commentsTextLabel];
[commentsTextLabel release];
```

Comment: modify the frame according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to set setNumberOfLines to 0. And it does't work us I understand your post?

Comment: number of lines 0 means you can add infinite number of lines. apple documentation says that:-This property controls the maximum number of lines to use in order to fit the label’s text into its bounding rectangle. The default value for this property is 1. To remove any maximum limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.

Comment: From iOS6 onwards `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` is deprecated. You can use `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`

Comment: You may need to set [label setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:labelSize.Width] if you are dealing with auto layout. see this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout

I was using the Masonry library to generate auto layout constraints and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try before setText:

```
cell.exsInfoLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Or:

```
cell.exsInfoLabel.numberOfLines = arrEx.count;
```