# iOS AutoLayout multi-line UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

Following question is sort-of continuation of this one:

[iOS: Multi-line UILabel in Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout)

The main idea is that every view is supposed to state it's "preferred" (intrinsic) size so that AutoLayout can know how to display it properly. 
UILabel is just an example of a situation where a view **cannot** by itself know what size it needs for display. It depends on what width is provided.

As **mwhuss** pointed out, *setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth* did the trick of making the label span across multiple lines. But that is not the main question here. The question is where and when do I get this *width* value that I send as an argument to *setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth*.

I managed to make something that looks legit, so correct me if I am wrong in any way and tell me please if you know a better way.

In the UIView's

```
-(CGSize) intrinsicContentSize
```

I *setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth* for my UILabels according to self.frame.width.

UIViewController's

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

is the first callback method I know where subviews of the main view are appointed with their exact frames that they inhabit on the screen. From inside that method I, then, operate on my subviews, invalidating their intrinsic sizes so that UILabels are broken into multiple lines based on the width that was appointed to them.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It seems annoying that a UILabel doesn't default to its width for the preferred max layout width, if you've got constraints that are unambiguously defining that width for you.

In nearly every single case I've used labels under Autolayout, the preferred max layout width has been the actual width of the label, once the rest of my layout has been performed.

So, to make this happen automatically, I have used a UILabel subclass, which overrides `setBounds:`. Here, call the super implementation, then, **if it isn't the case already**, set the preferred max layout width to be the bounds size width.

The emphasis is important - setting preferred max layout causes another layout pass to be performed, so you can end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, man. Totally forgot about the "setBounds". This is actually what I was looking for as a point where a subview is appointed its size.
I was trying setFrame and it's not being called. But I'm not really knowledgeable about these things, so tnx once again.

Comment: Under iOS8 if the UILabel is in a tableview cell, setBounds doesn't seem to be called. Is there any way to calculate a good initial guess at `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`?

Comment: @RogerNolan haven't had the time to look at it on iOS8 yet(!) Will update if and when I get the chance, or you might want to ask a new question

Comment: I just posted a solution to this question that works on iOS 7 and iOS 8

Comment: @RogerNolan It worked for me. Did you set the class of the UILabel in the xib file to the custom class ? I've a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell's contentView. I subclassed the UILabel and set the custom class in the xib file. As soon as I set the custom class in the xib file, it started calling the setBounds: method.

Comment: @RogerNolan Any solution for UILabel inside tableview for iOS8?

Comment: @zala In iOS8 the preferred max layout width of "automatic" for the label should render this unnecessary

Comment: I'am also supporting iOS 7 so I have set max layout width as "Explicit". Now I want change the max layout width for iOS 8 programatically.

Answer (score 64):

There's an answer this question on [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/) in the "Intrinsic Content Size of Multi-Line Text" section of [Advanced Auto Layout Toolbox](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html). Here's the relevant info:

> The intrinsic content size of UILabel and NSTextField is ambiguous for multi-line text. The height of the text depends on the width of the lines, which is yet to be determined when solving the constraints. In order to solve this problem, both classes have a new property called preferredMaxLayoutWidth, which specifies the maximum line width for calculating the intrinsic content size.
>
> Since we usually don’t know this value in advance, we need to take a two-step approach to get this right. First we let Auto Layout do its work, and then we use the resulting frame in the layout pass to update the preferred maximum width and trigger layout again.

The code they give for use inside a view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = myLabel.frame.size.width;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Take a look at their post, there's more information about why it's necessary to do the layout twice.

Comment: @AlexanderLongbeach I'm not sure what you mean. The label is always inside a subview. It's impossible to have a `UILabel` that's not inside a subview.

Comment: I mean. All the examples here count on that you know the size of the label's superview, but if that superview also has been added using auto layout without hardcoding a width.. what then? This might be a dumb question, but Im new to auto layout..

Comment: @AlexanderLongbeach The example above actually doesn't rely on having a hardcoded width in the superview.  In fact, you could almost always use label.superview.frame.size.width, without even needing a direct pointer to the superview.

Comment: Seeing claims that iOS 7 handles this for you: http://danielgarbien.com/ios/2013/11/16/preferredMaxLayoutWidth.html

Comment: Update. That article is incorrect. Still required until iOS 8.

Comment: Either the superviews width is defined by the size of the label (ie inverse intrinsic content size inheritance), or the superview will know it's correct frame after [super layoutSubviews] has been called for the first time

Comment: What about if the label is inside a UITableViewCell and the view controller can change?

Comment: In my case this wasn't working on iOS 8, because `myLabel.frame.size.width` was zero. On iOS 7 `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was called three times (first with zero and than with the correct frame value) - on iOS 8 only one time. Now I used `self.view.bounds.size.width` and now it is working fine.

Comment: Subclassing `UILabel` as described in [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html) does also the job for me. Now it works for iOS 7 and iOS 8.

Comment: I did this in a UILabel subclass and it works:  `- (void)updateConstraints {
    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    [super updateConstraints];
}`

Answer (score 33):

**Update**

My original answer appears to be helpful so I have left it untouched below, however, in my own projects I have found a more reliable solution that works around bugs in iOS 7 and iOS 8.
https://github.com/nicksnyder/ios-cell-layout

**Original answer**

This is a complete solution that works for me on iOS 7 and iOS 8

**Objective C**

```
@implementation AutoLabel

- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  if (bounds.size.width != self.bounds.size.width) {
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  }
  [super setBounds:bounds];
}

- (void)updateConstraints {
  if (self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != self.bounds.size.width) {
    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
  }
  [super updateConstraints];
}

@end
```

**Swift**

```
import Foundation

class EPKAutoLabel: UILabel {

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            if (bounds.size.width != oldValue.size.width) {
                self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints();
            }
        }
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if(self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != self.bounds.size.width) {
            self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width
        }
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I adapt this logic because i just need to remove the Xcode warning for label when label.numberOfLines = 0;

Comment: This worked for me in iOS 8 from within a UITableViewCell.

Comment: This is also the only suggestion that worked for me inside UITableViewCell.  Thanks a lot

Comment: This didn't work for me on iOS 7!

I added this:
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);

    [super layoutSubviews];
}

Comment: Works perfectly in both collections and tables, make lists and collections fluid by not adding massive label bounds recomputations like other solutions.

Comment: I don't think that swift version is ever going to fire the `self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` line. It should be checking if `bounds.size.width != oldValue.size.width`. The way it is currently written is comparing the value with itself.

Answer (score 10):

We had a situation where an auto-layouted UILabel inside a UIScrollView laid out fine in portrait, but when rotated to landscape the height of the UILabel wasn't recalculated.

We found that the answer from @jrturton fixed this, presumably because now the preferredMaxLayoutWidth is correctly set.

Here's the code we used. Just set the Custom class from Interface builder to be *CVFixedWidthMultiLineLabel*.

**CVFixedWidthMultiLineLabel.h**

```
@interface CVFixedWidthMultiLineLabel : UILabel

@end
```

**CVFixedWidthMultiLineLabel.m**

```
@implementation CVFixedWidthMultiLineLabel

// Fix for layout failure for multi-line text from
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491376/ios-autolayout-multi-line-uilabel
- (void) setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    [super setBounds:bounds];

    if (bounds.size.width != self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth) {
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Having the same problem but this isn't working for me unfortunately. I'm working with labels inside of a tableView

Comment: This solution works pretty well with one caveat. I was using label in tableView and in heightForRowAtIndexpath I'm ordinary do 'systemLayoutSizeFittingSize' in order to get correct cell dimensions. However before calling this method you have to update cell width as 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' will return it in size defined in xib file(mine was 320, actual size 227). So update cell frame = tableView.contentSize.width before calling layoutIfNeeded combined with this solution happens to work on all devices(4s, 5, 6, 6+).

Comment: The only this approach worked for me (within a UICollectionViewCell) was to set the initial frame when calculating the size.

Answer (score 2):

### Using boundingRectWithSize

I resolved my struggle with two multi-line labels in a legacy `UITableViewCell` that was using "\n" as a line-break by measuring the desired width like this:

```
- (CGFloat)preferredMaxLayoutWidthForLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
    CGFloat preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 0.0f;
    NSString *text = label.text;
    UIFont *font = label.font;
    if (font != nil) {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *mutableParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        mutableParagraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: [mutableParagraphStyle copy]};
        CGRect boundingRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeZero options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
        preferredMaxLayoutWidth = ceilf(boundingRect.size.width);

        NSLog(@"Preferred max layout width for %@ is %0.0f", text, preferredMaxLayoutWidth);
    }


    return preferredMaxLayoutWidth;
}
```

Then calling the method was then as simple as:

```
CGFloat labelPreferredWidth = [self preferredMaxLayoutWidthForLabel:textLabel];
if (labelPreferredWidth > 0.0f) {
    textLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = labelPreferredWidth;
}
[textLabel layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Can I use the same approach for calculating the label height?

Answer (score 2):

As I'm not allowed to add a comment, I'm obliged to add it as an answer.
The version of jrturton only worked for me if I call `layoutIfNeeded` in `updateViewConstraints` before getting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of the label in question.
Without the call to `layoutIfNeeded` the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` was always `0` in `updateViewConstraints`. And yet, it had always the desired value when checked in `setBounds:`. I didn't manage to get to know WHEN the correct `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` was set. I override `setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:` on the `UILabel` subclass, but it never got called.

Summarized, I:

- ...sublcassed UILabel
- ...and override `setBounds:` to, **if not already set**, set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to `CGRectGetWidth(bounds)`
- ...call `[super updateViewConstraints]` before the following
- ...call `layoutIfNeeded` before getting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to be used in label's size calculation

**EDIT:** This workaround only seems to work, or be needed, sometimes. I just had an issue (iOS 7/8) where the label's height were not correctly calculated, as `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` returned `0` after the layout process had been executed once. So after some trial and error (and having found this [Blog entry](http://danielgarbien.com/ios/2013/11/16/preferredMaxLayoutWidth.html)) I switched to using `UILabel` again and just set top, bottom, left and right auto layout constraints. And for whatever reason the label's height was set correctly after updating the text.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by another answer I tried to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _subtitleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 40;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This worked, but it was visible on the UI and caused a "visible flicker" i.e. first the label was rendered with the height of two lines, then it was re-rendered with the height of only one line.

This was not acceptable for me.

I found then a better solution by overriding `updateViewConstraints`:

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    // Multiline-Labels and Autolayout do not work well together:
    // In landscape mode the width is still "portrait" when the label determines the count of lines
    // Therefore the preferredMaxLayoutWidth must be set
    _subtitleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 40;
}
```

This was the better solution for me, because it did not cause the "visual flickering".

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution is to set `rowcount = 0` and to use a property for the heightconstraint of your label. Then after the content is set call

```
CGSize sizeThatFitsLabel = [_subtitleLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_subtitleLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
_subtitleLabelHeightConstraint.constant = ceilf(sizeThatFitsLabel.height);
```

`-(void) updateViewConstraints` has a problem since iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8, you can fix multi-line label layout problems in a cell by calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` after dequeuing and configuring the cell. The call is harmless in iOS 9.

See Nick Snyder's answer. This solution was taken from his code at https://github.com/nicksnyder/ios-cell-layout/blob/master/CellLayout/TableViewController.swift.