# UITableView resize cell based on content

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, ios8, autolayout

Hi I need help with understanding how to resize cell based on its content.

So first of all of course I found many links:

[iOS: Multi-line UILabel in Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkvZEJ7dIfw

https://github.com/williamhqs/GSTableViewDynamicHeight

As we said about git example (last link) I can't understand how to change some label and make it works. For example if I delete UILabel and create new one and bind it with content property (content - it is IBOutlet property of bottom label). I seems lost some setting and cell won't stretch.

So I think I don't know to much understanding how to do it.

What I want to understand:

1. How to setup auto layouts in the storyboard or programmatically.
2. Which thing I should handle programmatically to make it done.
3. How the preferred size affects on label. Do we need every time use bonds of superview as a preferred size?

Also in the git example we have one label that changes itself size. What if we have 2 UILabels with dynamic content how to setup it?

If you have some links or videos please drop them here, because I really stuck. Thank you!

I know it's duplicated question but I can't understand how to setup it.

Answer (score 2):

To make Self Sizing Cells works there is three steps:

1. Setup correctly the constraints of the cell  (most important the top and bottom constraints)
2. Specify the `estimatedRowHeight` of your table view
3. Set the `rowHeight` of your table view to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

for step 2 and 3 it's so easy just add these two lines in you viewDidLoad method

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // or whatever you want
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

for step 1 which is the most important part of self sizing process 
what you need to keep in mind is that **"self-sizing needs to get its size from your constraints."**

Basically we need to make sure that top space and bottom space constraints of our cell is correctly set up here is an example :

[image: self sizing cell]

just two labels with the constraints top,bottom,right and left space to each other and to container (see image) the `UILabels` Lines property is 0 so that you allow have multiple lines

Another example from a project that I am working on:

[image: auto size cell]

bottom line:

**The label constraints should push against the size of the table view cell and make it taller. So always check the top and bottom constraints.**

Also you may run intro trouble working with UILabel with multi-lines because

> The intrinsic content size of UILabel and NSTextField is ambiguous for
>   multi-line text.

so make sure always to setup the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property of yout label:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.contentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.contentLabel.frame.size.width;

}
```

for more infrmation about this issue here read :

[iOS Autolayout multi line UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491376/ios-autolayout-multi-line-uilabel)

[iOS multi-line UILabel in Auto-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout)

[preferredMaxLayoutWidth](http://danielgarbien.com/ios/2013/11/16/preferredMaxLayoutWidth.html)

And for more information about  Dynamic Table View Cell Height in general here is some useful resources:

[UITableView Tutorial: Dynamic Table View Cell Height](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift)

[Understanding Self Sizing Cells and Dynamic Type in iOS 8](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

[Self Sizing Table View Cells](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html)

[Mysteries of Auto Layout, Part 1 (wwdc 2015)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=218)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will apply to AutoLayout, although when laying out a cell programmatically, running "layoutIfNeeded()" fixed my cell content stretch issue.

layoutIfNeeded was ran at the end of a configure method, used to map values (view model) to UI objects (views)