# UICollectionViewCell autolayout for UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have some problems with autolayout and `UICollectionViewCell` . You can see cell prototype scheme below. Green rectangle is `UILabel` and 2 red rectangles are UIImages.

I have defined following constraints:

- `UILabel` is centered in cell
- `UILabel` has fixed top spacing to cell (5pt)
- `UIImages` and `UILabel` has center Y alignment
- `UIImage` and `UILabel` has defined horizontal spacing (5pt)

My goal is:
I need to stretch my `label` according to its contentSize, so `UIImages` are exactly 5 pt from text, not from `UILabel` border.

Is it possible without calculating in code and assigning values to width constraint?

[image: Cell image]

Comment: What about the space between `UIImage`s and cell's border? Are they fixed?

Comment: @trick14 No, it can be any value startingfrom 0 pt

Answer (score 0):

If your green label is multiline, you can use `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property of `UILabel`.

Example:

```
self.myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 300; // or whatever value you like
```

For more details look at [iOS: Multi-line UILabel in Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout)