# How to set autolayouts and content size in xib for multiline label in scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am using autolayout. In xib i have a scrollview as a parent view. Added one view as a subview. For that subview i have added four child elements. Three are views(say view1,view2,view3) and one is label which is having multiline text.

I am using the below code to change the height of the view

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view1Height;
self.view1Height.constant = 200;
```

In this case there is no issues with content size the view2 and view3 frames are adjusted automatically.

But while coming to multiline label I am using the below code for setting label text

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textLabelHeight;
    self.textLabelHeight.constant = expectedLabelSize.height;
```

But here I am facing issue with scroll content size. Unable to view the entire text. Similarly I want to place one more view below the label how to set constraints for it.

Comment: The property doesn't help us much if we don't see how you set it up in IB - a layout constraint consists of more than just the constant....

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: Multi-line UILabel in Auto Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout)