# Self sizing cell with multiple labels does not show multiline label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6, uistoryboard

I'm having three labels in my static table view cell and the middle label should be a multiline one.

I'm setting these two lines in `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 130.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

The storyboard looks like this

[image]

Here are the constraints for each subview

Top label, middle label, bottom label, button

[image]

I've also set the number of lines for the middle label to 0. However it only shows one single line, instead of multiple lines. I guess it must have something to do with content hugging or content compression priorities or it's because my I'm using a `UITableViewController` with static cells.

**UPDATE**

If I change Vertical Compression Resistance Priority of the middle label to 751 and Vertical Content Hugging Priority to 250, the label shows multilines, but the cell does not get resized, so the top and the bottom label are outside the cell now.

**UPDATE 2**

I've just created a sample project and it turned out that it works with dynamic cells as expected but not with static cells. You can download the sample project here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67692950/ResizingCell.zip

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make the label as tall as it needs to be to display all the lines?

Comment: @luk2302 yes, in an automatic way

Comment: you may want to take a look at [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout)

Comment: I'm afraid these answers are out of date for iOS 8 and self sizing cells

Comment: Have you set the line break mode on the middle label to "word wrap"?

Comment: @P-double yes have also done that, lines to 0 and line break mode to word wrap.

Comment: I'm confused, you say it works with dynamic cells but not static? what exactly do you mean

Comment: @gpichler why did you remove the dropbox link, can you please upload it and provide new link, I have similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cloned your sample project. I think the problem is that you don't need to set UITableViewCell's height.

This is the one simple solution.

[image]

・To set Row Height "Default" in Table View Cell.(Unchecked Custom)

In this case, it works.

Download the sample project that I implemented here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8q6ov9qjfxu1l3/ResizingCell.zip?dl=0

But the other way is that you calculate UITableViewCell's height from UILabel's height.

If you customize cell more complicatedly, it is better to isolate cell as a Custom cell.

Comment: It doesn't work when you set the bottom label as a multi-line label.

Comment: @pixyzehn i need help

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, open storyboard, set your tableview row height to be 100, uncheck custom row height for the tableview cell, which value is currently 100.

Secondly, like @DBoyer said, call `layoutIfNeeded`. If you see "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints, Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint X", lower X's priority to 999. I think the warnings may have something to do with that when you get the cell, cell frame is `CGRectZero`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either call `layoutIfNeeded` on the cell after setting the text of the multiline label or set the labels `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`

Comment: it's a `UITableViewController` with static cells, so I can't call it on the cell directly, also `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` should be done automatically in iOS 8

Comment: @user1463853 You can call it directly, just override `tableView:willDisplayCell:`

Answer (score 0):

Use aspectRatio constraint for labels. Its puspose is to change width aswell as height according to need.This will help