# UILabel double line and constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

So the main problem is showing in the picture itself. How can I make a double line horizontally label using my constraints, so I could show the entire text without cutting it?

[image]

Comment: What are the constraints you have on your UILabel?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with two changes,

1. Set the `Lines` field in attribute inspector to `0`
2. Do not specify a fixed height constraint for your UILabel.

**Update:**

In order to make the constraints to behave properly for a given UI element, you will have to have a minimum of 4 constraints on it.

1. Constraint to define its X position
2. Constraint to define its Y position
3. Constraint to define the width of the element
4. Constraint to define the height of the element

Since I do not have a clear picture of what your UI would look like, I'm giving a simple example. Assuming you have two labels one below the other and you want multi-line behavior for the second `UILabel`.

1. Define your X position, add a `leading edge` constraint to the margin or the edge based on your requirement
2. Define your Y position, add a `vertical spacing` constraint from your second label to the first label
3. To define the width, add a `trailing edge` constraint to the trailing margin or the edge
4. To define the height, add `height >= 20` (or the number you need) constraint

And ensure you have the `lines` property to be `0`.

Comment: Thank you RP, did the 1st step but couldn't understand well the 2nd one. Because I think I don't have any fixed height, or didn't understand what you meant. The label has 2 constraints as I can see, a Center Y alignment constraint and Horizontal space contraint. I think is related to the first one. Here is a pic about I have https://i.imgur.com/wAYmdZG.png

Comment: Check out this SO question to understand further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

> You can do with on storyboard. Click it later look at bottom side Resolve >Auto Layout Issues and click update frames. i think auto do this.

Thanks