# UILabel not displaying everything

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, sizetofit

I'm seriously lost on this one.

Here's the shot:

[image]

The price on Tea's Tea Matcha... is being cut off. I simply cannot figure out why.

I'm using boundingRectWithSize:...

When I log the height of the label's frame after calling layoutIfNeeded, it's the height that it should be for each respective frame: the same height as boundingRect.size.height.

Also, when I log the text of the label, the price is in the log so it's not that either.

It's just this and a few other labels out of hundreds that are having this issue and I do not know why.

This is my code for setting the height of the label:

```
CGRect boundingRect = [self.nameLabel.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

self.nameLabelHeightConstraint.constant = ceil(boundingRect.size.height);
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

One thing I've noticed - if instead of calculating the height with boundingRect and setting it manually I use sizeToFit on the label, it has this same problem but if I scroll past the row and back to it, it's fixed and the price appears underneath.

Anyone know wtf is going on here?

Comment: have you tried sizeToFit?

Comment: did you read my question? i already said i tried it. when i use sizeToFit it doesn't fix the problem at first but if I scroll past the troubling row and back to it, it's fixed then.

Comment: can you show more code? are you using this on a collection view?

Comment: yes its a collection view. not sure what else code to show. anything in particular you want to see? i am using autolayout if that matters.

Comment: I've experienced problems when using autoLayout and trying to move view/change sizes. might be it....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13032251/2164705 
take a look at this

Comment: that didnt do it. does autolayout still take effect on a view thats had all constraints removed? i cannot manually change the label's frame even though all constraints have been deleted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107982/discussion-between-tony-friz-and-ricardo-alves).

Answer (score 0):

I found I was able to fix the issue by changing the default height constraint constant. I lowered it significantly (it was large enough that it was touching the bottom of the Cell.xib view. I made it spaced closer to the view above it by 1 pixel, lowered the default height constraint constant in IB and changed the type from equals to greater than or equal to. These things combined (I'm not sure which if not all did it) seem to have fixed the problem.